# What do these mean in print?

Tags: python

```
def greater_less_equal_5(answer):
if answer > 5:
    return 1
elif answer < 5:          
    return -1
else:
    return 0

print greater_less_equal_5(4)
print greater_less_equal_5(5)
print greater_less_equal_5(6)
```

What these number: 4,5,6 mean and do in the ending of print?

Comment: 4, 5, 6 are passed as parameters respectively into the function and the value that it returns is printed on the screen. see - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm to learn more about functions.

Comment: @RohinGopalakrishnan Well in the OP's case, `print` is a statement not a function. It was changed to a function however, in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are arguments/parameters being passed to the function `greater_less_equal_5` as the value of `answer` to be used inside the body of that function. For example, `greater_less_equal_5(4)` effectively runs this code:

```
if 4 > 5:
    return 1
elif 4 < 5:          
    return -1
else:
    return 0
```

This has nothing to do with the `print`.